# How can you tell if JAVA_HOME contains a JDK in a Windows batch file?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, environment-variables, java-7

Is it possible to tell if a `JAVA_HOME` system environment variable contains a JDK within a Windows batch file?

Comment: What do you mean by "contains a JDK"? Do you mean if the executable exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're checking to see if the compiler exists, you could do something like:

```
if exist %JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac.exe (
   ...
) else (
   ...
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could look for %JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac.exe (or whatever it is, I assume exe).  That should not exist in a JRE, only in the JDK.